# Importing an image from another folder into eclipse

Tags: java, matlab

I have compiled my entire project in eclipse and it works file.

I have a class file `Embed.java`,that uses Mat-lab,what it basically does is shows the output in Mat-lab while using the java API.
I have achieved this using the open source 'Mat-lab Control Google Code'

My code contains two images,I have tried to import the images performing the basic steps,

```
Project -> Right click -> Import -> General -> File System
```

But it gives me an error(in Mat-lab) that the image does not exist.

I have also copy-pasted the images in the `src` folder(the one that is automatically created in Eclipse) but still gives me the same error.
Apart from this I have done some reading of posts in this forum, but it has not helped me.

Comment: Paste the Java code from your program that you are using to load the image from the file system.  Also paste the runtime stack trace.

Comment: @Charles thanks for your immediate response.The code is working perfectly now.This is what I did: Import the images into Referenced Libraries(Note:Refernced Libraries is a folder that is automatically created in eclipse when you import an external jar file),I did not write any java code to point to the images.And it worked magically:) thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag and drop the pictures from where you have them on your system into the source tree in Eclipse (left side). You should then get a popup asking whether or not to copy the images to the folder or move the original picture to the folder.

The problem could also be that you are not pointing to the right place where your images are stored in your source code.

Comment: thanks for your immediate response.The code is working perfectly now.This is what I did: Import the images into Referenced Libraries(Note:Refernced Libraries is a folder that is automatically created in eclipse when you import an external jar file),I did not write any java code to point to the images.And it worked magically:) thankyou.

Comment: I wouldn't put the pictures in **that** folder, but whatever works.